# В IE7 не работает JSON

Tags: jquery, json, internet-explorer

Имею такую ошибку:

> SCRIPT5009: 'JSON' is undefined jquery.jsoncookie.js, line 50 character 3

В плагине jquery.jsoncookie.js 3 не находит 'JSON'.

```
SCRIPT5009: 'JSON' is undefined 
jquery.jsoncookie.js, line 50 character 3

document.cookie = [
        key, "=", encode( JSON.stringify( value ) ),
        expires ? "; expires=" + expires.toUTCString() : "",
        options.path ? "; path=" + options.path : "",
        options.domain ? "; domain=" + options.domain : "",
        options.secure ? "; secure" : ""
    ].join( "" );
```

Comment: И не работает только в IE? O_o

Comment: Да, только в IE7.

Comment: спасибо помогло.

Answer (score 1):

А вы реализацию JSON подключили (как написано [здесь](https://github.com/appendto/jquery-jsoncookie/blob/master/readme.md) внизу)? У IE 7 нет нативного объекта JSON.